# Lookup values based on third colum in Sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint list A:

```
Person | Job 
John     Blue Collar
Billy    White Collar
Tracy    CEO
```

Where A.**Job** is a lookup column getting options from list B:

```
Job Title    | Job Status
Blue Collar    Open
White Collar   Open
CEO            Closed
```

I want **A.Job** to only show options from **B.Job Title** WHERE **B.Job Status** is 'Open'

Is it possible to do this in SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a calculated column in list B, and choose whether to use the value of Job Title according to the status.
[image]
Formula:`=IF([Job Status]="open",[Job Title],"")`

Then list B get the value from the calculated column.

[image]
[image]